# Reading a binary tree from the console in c

Tags: c

I am trying to read a binary tree into my program using the following function that i wrote.

```
void readTree(struct Dnode *root)
{
    struct Dnode *temp;
    struct Dnode *input;
    char initData;

    scanf(" %c",&initData);
    input=CreateNode(initData);

    if(initData==122){
        printf("Leaf\n");
        return;
    }
    else {
        root=input;
        temp=root;
        printf("going to left of %c\n",initData);
        readTree(root->lLink);
        printf("going to right of %c\n",initData);
        readTree(root->rLink);
    }
}
```

Everything is working fine except the fact that , in main the tree doesnt exist. Here is my main program:

```
int main()
{
    int n=0;
    struct Dnode *root=NULL;
    printf("Enter the tree as it asks. Enter z whenever there is no children :\n");
    readTree(root);
    printf("%c",root->data);
    printf("In main");
    return;

 }
```

The program suddenly crashes after inputting the tree.Please help me.

Comment: Remember that in C arguments are passed *by value*, i.e. copied, and inside the function those arguments are just like any other local variable and will go out of scope when the function returns, and all changes to the arguments will be lost. Please search for *emulating pass by reference in c*. The problem would have been very obvious if you just spent a couple of minutes in a debugger stepping through your code.

Comment: Your program is reading from the keyboard (or whatever standard input device you're using), not from the console (or whatever standard output device you're using).

Comment: input? expected output? actual output? what is `struct Dnode`? what is `CreateNode`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some problems with your code.

1) You want the function to change root but it doesn't

In main `root` is a `struct Dnode*` and the function takes a `struct Dnode*`. Since C uses pass-by-value it means that any change made inside the function is lost when the function returns.

In other words - when the function returns, `root` in `main` **is still** `NULL`. Then you do: `printf("%c",root->data);` which chrashes because you are dereferencing `NULL`.

Instead the function should take a double-pointer, i.e. `struct Dnode**`. Inside the function you must use `*root = ....` when assigning. And the function must be called like `readTree(&root);`

2) You never save the the node when it is a leaf.

3) The variable `temp` is never used.

4) The name `root` is confusing for a recursive function

Putting this together, your code could be:

```
void readTree(struct Dnode **current)  // Double pointer
{
    struct Dnode *input;
    char initData;

    scanf(" %c",&initData);
    input=CreateNode(initData);

    *current=input; // Save the created

    if(initData==122){
        printf("Leaf\n");
        return;
    }
    else {
        printf("going to left of %c\n",initData);
        readTree(&((*current)->lLink));
        printf("going to right of %c\n",initData);
        readTree(&((*current)->rLink));
    }
}
```

From main call it like:

```
readTree(&root);
         ^
         notice
```

Comment: Thank you very much 4386427. Your attention to details while explaining helped me a lot. The code worked.

Answer (score 0):

You must understand that the values passed to a function as an argument and the parameter of the evoked function are the same, but totally different two local variables.

When your function readTree() is evoked, a local variable root is declared and the value is automatically initiated as the same value you passed into a function when evoked.
The variable, root in main(), and the root in readTree() are different two variables but have the same value.

In the function readTree(), you're creating a new node and binding the returned value to the variable root in readTree(). As I wrote, the two roots are not identical. Therefore, your changes, bindings, have no effects out of the scope - readTree() and the root in main() remains unchanged.

To handle this problem, you must pass the pointer to pointer to struct Dnode.

Like this, in main function,

```
struct Dnode *root;
readTree(&root);
```

and readTree() must also be changed

```
readTree(struct Dnode **root)
```

Comment: Thank you very much John Park. I will not make such mistakes again. The code worked.